# How can i set the type of indy tcp client to non blocking mode?

Tags: sockets, delphi, client-server, delphi-7, indy

```
 idTCPClient1.Port := strtoInt(Port.text);
 idTCPClient1.Host := IP.Text;
 idTCPClient1.connect;
```

How can i set the socket to non blocking mode?

Comment: Use it in a separate thread. Indy are blocking components.

Comment: Indy uses blocking sockets exclusively, there is no non-blocking option.  You have to use worker threads if you want to perform operations asynchronously.

Comment: You can't. Indy is blocking.

Comment: Thanks! That helped.